# Filter for datepicker ui.bootstrap in AngularJs (2014-04-17T07:00:00.000Z )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a angular app, and y save date from a datepicker ui.bootstrap, i wanna filter the date and show readble date..

Example:
**2014-04-17T07:00:00.000Z to 4/14/2014 or other option**

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Angular filter of date.

```
{{date  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss}}
```

See the following link - [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate)

**Example** (**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/30/)**)

**html**

```
   <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
            <li ng-repeat="arr in records ">
                {{arr.date| date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
            </li>
   </div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.records = [{
        name: 'sohn',
        phone: '555-1212',
        age: 10,
        date: '2014-11-12T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '555-9876',
        age: 19,
        date: '2014-05-17T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321',
        age: 21,
        date: '2014-04-17T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678',
        age: 35,
        date: '2014-09-01T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        date: '2014-10-21T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        date: '2014-11-12T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'arlina',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        date: '2014-07-07T07:00:00.000Z'},
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        date: '2014-06-07T07:00:00.000Z'}
    ];
});
```

**Output**

```
11/12/2014
05/17/2014
04/17/2014
09/01/2014
10/21/2014
11/12/2014
07/07/2014
06/07/2014
```